# IE/Edge styles applied in different order compared to other browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, microsoft-edge, video.js

I am finding that styles are being applied in a different order in IE edge compared to chrome.

Example
on this site http://videojs.com/ inspecting this element

```html
<div poster="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" preload="auto" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-paused preview-player-dimensions vjs-controls-enabled vjs-workinghover vjs-v6 vjs-mux vjs-user-inactive" id="preview-player" lang="en-us" role="region" aria-label="Video Player"><video id="preview-player_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" preload="auto" poster="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" tabindex="-1">
...
</div>
```

IE

[image]

Chrome

[image]

what is the reason for the difference?

Comment: Right now this question is a game of spot-the-difference. Please call out the differences you see and don't understand, *as text*, in the question.

Comment: Is the applied css actually different or just the order shown to you in the inspector?

Comment: Separately: There is no "IE edge," IE and Edge are different browsers. Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using edge browser. To be more specific let's take `.video-js` class. there are two styles for it in the CSS one in video-js.css and one as an internal CSS. In chrome, the video-js.css has higher specificity than the internal CSS. In Edge, the internal CSS has higher specificity than video-js.css. Shouldn't be the same in both browsers?

Answer (score 1):

The order that each browser lists the styles in is not the order that they are actually applied to the element. This can be easily seen by comparing the two lists. Although they may list certain selectors in a different order, both are applying them equally (neither browser is applying something that the other browser isn't). Each browser vendor is free to set up their development tools in whatever way they like - there are no standards to follow on that. So, it's perfectly reasonable to expect differences in how various browsers report information in their tools.

There are specific rules about CSS selector **["specificity"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)** and what selectors will override others. Both of those browsers are standards complaint and apply the specificity rules equally.

**Only when two selectors have identical specificity**, and when the properties set in those selectors conflict with each other, will the location of the selectors (relative to each other) in the overall CSS be a factor.

Both your `div` and your `video` elements have `id`s as well as classes applied to them, so there are multiple styles being applied with different specificity. Also, the `video` element is nested within the `div`, so inherited CSS properties come into play.

Understanding CSS specificity is the key to solving your issue.

Comment: Wouldn't the same class selector placed below override itself?

Comment: @Adriani6 Yes, but other selectors may be overriding that.

Comment: Of course, that's just the basics. My guess is that OP worries more about his classes not being applied in order

Comment: @Adriani6 That's why the answer here is to understand specificity.